# Is it a bad practice using email address in GET requests in Hypermedia API

Tags: api, rest, url, url-parameters, hypermedia

I'm currently in the design process of an hypermedia REST API. I want to know if there is any recommendation about passing email addresses as URL parameter in GET requests.

thanks in advance

Comment: Just make sure you percent escape it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emails are usually not seen as critical or sigilous information, and therefore can be transported in open.

If you would like to offer some security, just encode the email using some transformation, then decode on the server.